# How can I redirect request from one site to a sub-domain site?

Tags: routes, asp.net-core

You can see Google has the following scenario:

**http://www.google.com/shopping** renders a web site that seems like a separate web site than the google.com web site.

How can I achieve the same scenario with ASP.NET 5?

Comment: This question is far too broad. You'll need to be much more specific. That and the question title does not reflect on the question content in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It's responsibility your http server, not asp.net 5 application.
If you use IIS, you have to tune virtual directory.

read this articles:

1. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx
2. www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

At Azure WebApps this settings are in "Settings". See this image: i.stack.imgur.com/zEfx9.jpg